# Why doesn't couchbase plugin load?

Tags: nativescript, couchbase-lite, nativescript-plugin

I use the latest NativeScript Sidekick and Preview for developing (vanilla, pure JS) apps, recently I installed Couchbase Lite Plugin https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-couchbase

When I write `var couchbaseModule = require("nativescript-couchbase");` in
the JS file of a page and if I try to open the page, this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5db5.png) shows up

But if I remove `var couchbaseModule = require("nativescript-couchbase");` the page loads without error.

Why this happens? How can I use and require couchbase plugin? What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Limitations](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview#command-limitations)

> The Preview app comes with a predefined set of NativeScript plugins. If your app utilizes a plugin that is not present in the Preview app, you will see a warning message and your app might not work as expected.

`nativescript-couchbase` plugin is dependent on their native libraries, so you must have complete environment setup to build your project locally in order to test it. Preview won't support this plugin.

Comment: But building apk every time is time consuming and it reduces cloud builds, how can I preview my project with external plugins like couchbase and barcode scanner? or is there any easier way to test it with these plugins without having to build the app?

Comment: At least as of today, it's not possible at all. It's not a limitation with {N}. You must have to recompile your app when you have new native dependencies, Objective C / Java code requires a compiler unlike JavaScript which works with an interpreter. If you use any plugin that purely depends on JavaScript / any existing native libraries within your OS, you don't have to recompile, otherwise you must. You could setup Android SDK locally on your machine and build APK yourself.